# product export makes backend inaccessible. sql seems to be idle. How to find the bottleneck?

Tags: performance, importexport

I'm running a default Magento product export. The shop contain over 30K products. That will take some time - sure! But if I open a new tab to continue working with the backend I just get a blank screen and the browser only continues loading...
If I run

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

I see that most of the time mysql is idle. Just one select every 5-7sec. So I assume there is a PHP issue somewhere or a bottleneck in writing the file to the hardrive? How can I check it / How can I improve the speed?
After 20 minutes the export finished and I got a success message. The second tab I had opened shows me a Magento default error message. The report says:

```
"a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:2422:"#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)"
```

So is it a mysql issue? But why is mysql idle most of the time? I'm very confused :(

Thank you so much for any help!

PHP Memory limit:
local: 1204M
master: 128M

PHP timeout: 60 sec (master/local)

Apache, PHP 5.3.3

Comment: You might have more change of getting a response on http://superuser.com/ for example as this is more about the server